# JPA entity update via "getById & save" didn't updated it's updatedtimestamp column

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm now trying to update the Entity's column by using "getById & save", like below.

```kotlin
// update "title" column 
val entityRef = entityRepository.getById(entityID)
entityRef.title = futureTitle 
return entityRepository.save(entityRef)
```

However, if I running the code, the updatedtimestamp column(which is described as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) not changed even though the column has been perfectly updated.

It seems like the `updatedtimestamp` column only updates when I use the custom "UPDATE" query.

```kotlin
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Entity p set p.title = :newTitle where p.id = :entityId")
    fun updateEntityTitle(entityId: Long, newTitle: String)
```

Could I know why updating entity by "getById & save" didn't made a change to the `updatedtimestamp`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a construct of MySql's SQL dialect. It is described as follows [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an auto-updated column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Since all JPA implementation update all columns no matter, if they changed or not they will also provide a value for your `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column thus preventing any automatic update as described in the documentation.

You have various ways to get an update timestamp with this technology stack:

1. You can use dynamic inserts to only update fields that changed. Note that in most cases this is bad for performance. See [Hibernate: Dirty Checking and Only Update of Dirty Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2674516/66686)
2. You can make the column read only by using `@Column(updatable=false)`. See [JPA readonly mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090941/jpa-readonly-mapping)
3. Instead of using the MySql feature you may use the [Hibernates `UpdateTimestamp` for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39427923/66686)
4. Or you use [JPAs `EntityListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221827/66686).
5. And since you seem to use Spring Data JPA you may also use [Spring Datas `@LastModifiedDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165624/66686).

Comment: Because `@LastModifiedDate` does not work on my case, (It seems like that I have to enable EnableJpaAuditing to my config class to use it) so I used `@Column(updatable=false)` and now it works :) thank you so much!